# Most efficient way to read data from file in Mathematica

Tags: import, string-manipulation, files-and-directories

So I am having trouble because I am trying to do with Mathematica what is equivalent do "sscanf" with C basically.

I will have a text file with a number of specifications:

data1 data2 data3 ...

Some of these parameters are strings, while others are numbers. Basically I want scan the line of the file and put each of these fields into variables. What is the best way to do this in Mathematica. I have seen very confusing information online, some using Import, others fread and I am still not sure what would be the best way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could start by  trying `Import` with `CSV` format. [CSV](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) and see how it works. What is the field separation? space, tab, comma?

Comment: Hi @Nasser! Thank you. As for the separation initially I was doing space, than changed to comma, but I am not sure what will be easier for Mathematica to do the interpretation (I am defining the format of the files myself so I can still change it).

Answer (score 8):

You may also check the [`ReadList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html) function.
For example considering following input (having an implicit structure of *String, Number, String, Number*):

```
abc 123 def 456
abcdef 123.123 defghj 456.456
```

you can read it like:

```
ReadList["input.txt", {Word, Number, Word, Number}]
```

and getting the result in form of a list of records `{{"abc", 123, "def", 456}, {"abcdef", 123.123, "defghj", 456.456}}`